# scaloid example layout doesn't work

Tags: android, scala, layout

I love Scaloid, but I'm struggling to get any layout working beyond a simple vertical stack of UI elements, including their home page's example.  This is the example code on scaloid's site:

```
   new SVerticalLayout {
      STextView("Sign in").textSize(24.5 sp).<<.marginBottom(25 dip).>>
      STextView("ID")
      SEditText()
      STextView("Password")
      SEditText() inputType TEXT_PASSWORD
      SButton("Sign in")
      this += new SLinearLayout {
        SButton("Help")
        SButton("Sign up")
      }
    }.padding(20 dip)
```

To try this, I did this:

```
class MyActivity extends SActivity {

      onCreate {

        contentView = new SVerticalLayout {
          STextView("Sign in").textSize(24.5 sp).<<.marginBottom(25 dip).>>
          STextView("ID")
          SEditText()
          STextView("Password")
          SEditText() inputType TEXT_PASSWORD
          SButton("Sign in")
          this += new SLinearLayout {
            SButton("Help")
            SButton("Sign up")
          }
        }.padding(20 dip)
      }
}
```

However, when I try this on my phone (Nexus 5 in portrait orientation), the "Sign Up" button doesn't appear.  The "Help" button spans the width of the screen.  My expectation is that the SLinearLayout would produce a horizontal layout embedded within the SVerticalLayout, and that I'd see the two buttons side by side.

So three questions:

1) Is the scaloid example correct?

2) Am I embedding it into my code correctly?  i.e. setting contentView to the SVerticalLayout?

3) How would I modify it to have the Help and Sign Up buttons appears side by side on a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the writer of the example. It is a bug. Thanks!

Every widget of Scaloid is set with `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"` by default. Because the "Help" button fills the parent, the "Sign up" is not seen.

A solution is that adding `.wrap`. The entire code becomes:

```
new SVerticalLayout {
  STextView("Sign in").textSize(24.5 sp).<<.marginBottom(25 dip).>>
  STextView("ID")
  SEditText()
  STextView("Password")
  SEditText() inputType TEXT_PASSWORD
  SButton("Sign in")
  this += new SLinearLayout {
    SButton("Help")
    SButton("Sign up")
  }.wrap
}.padding(20 dip)
```

The function `.wrap` applies `WRAP_CONTENT` for width and height:

https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid#methods-fill-and-wrap

Comment: Thanks very much.  It would be useful to add a note about the default to the readme doc, and an explanation of what .<<wrap.>> does.  What does .<<wrap.>> do?

Comment: I added a description about that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Those two buttons show up in a row if you explicitly specify their constraints like so:

```
SButton("Help").<<(WRAP_CONTENT, MATCH_PARENT)
```

The corrected example is:

```
 contentView = new SVerticalLayout {
    STextView("Sign in").textSize(24.5 sp).<<.marginBottom(25 dip).>>
      STextView("ID")
    SEditText()
    STextView("Password")
    SEditText() inputType TEXT_PASSWORD
    SButton("Sign in")
    this += new SLinearLayout {
      SButton("Help").<<(WRAP_CONTENT, MATCH_PARENT)
      SButton("Sign up").<<(WRAP_CONTENT, MATCH_PARENT)
    }
  }.padding(20 dip)
```